# Displaying contents of array in Fortran debugging

Tags: eclipse, fortran, fortran90, gfortran, intel-fortran

I am using GNU Fortran Compiler on Windows with Eclipse Fotran IDE. For debugging, I am trying to get contents of array in Eclipse. However, I did not find any good to resolve my problem.

If I set breakpoints and write `arr(1,1)` it gives garbage result, even though the array contains meaningful values. I was especially interested in viewing row-wise array contents, say `arr(1,:)`, `arr(2,:)`

I referred to this: [How to print Fortran arrays in GDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786958/how-to-print-fortran-arrays-in-gdb)  but I am trying to do it in the IDE.

There is another good post of how to display arrays in Eclipse, but it did not work for fortran. [Eclipse-C++-Debugging: see content of an Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824685/eclipse-c-debugging-see-content-of-an-array) When I right click the variable, there is no option to do the same what posted in this question.

Any comments how to do this?

EDIT: 
I wrote a simple program and compiled with gdb debugger.

```
PROGRAM test3
IMPLICIT NONE

REAL,DIMENSION(5) :: ARR1
REAL,DIMENSION (3,3) :: ARR2
ARR1=(/1,2,3,4,5/)
ARR2 = reshape((/ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 /), shape(ARR2))

WRITE(*,100) 'ARR1 = ',ARR1
100 FORMAT (F0.0)

WRITE(*,100) 'ARR2 = ',ARR2

END PROGRAM
```

Compiled: `gfortran -g test3.f90 -o test3`

Debugger:

```
gdb test3
break main
run
step
```

After stepping a few times,

```
print ARR2
$2 = (( 1, 2, 3) ( 4, 5, 6) ( 7, 8, 9) )
```

So, I got the array contents from the gdb in command line. But I want to do the same in IDE. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure your version of gdb supports Fortran array desciptors (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786958/how-to-print-fortran-arrays-in-gdb)? First make it work in gdb, only then move one to the IDE.

Comment: @VladimirF  I added the gdb commands and result. So, array printing works in gdb and I want to do it in IDE. Any ideas?

Comment: Any comments on displaying array contents in debugging mode?